# How to avoid the -generic suffix when using ants EJBJAR Task?

Tags: java, ant

I'm creating an ejb jar via  the `ejbjar` task in ant setting `naming="directory"` but it generates the jar with the name of the folder plus -generic.

Is it possible to skip this suffix via some property?

Comment: Can you post your AntScript for the task in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a genericjarsuffix parameter that defaults to "-generic.jar" and keepgeneric which defaults to "false" which determines whether the generic file used as input to the application server deployment tool(s) is retained.

The [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ejb.html#ejbjar) describes the options available for the different application servers.

Since keepgeneric defaults to "false", does your Ant script explicitly set this to "true" somewhere?

Comment: Oh yes i forgot about genericjarsuffix property )